# MySQl-getting salary of each dept

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I get the top two salary of each department? Table looks like:

```
-------------------------
name     dept      sal
-------------------------
name1    CSE       100000
name2    CSE       200000
name3    ECE       200000
name4    EEE       400000
name5    CSE       700000
name6    ECE       600000
```

Comment: have a look at my answer it will work as per your requirements :)

Comment: @Aziz Shaikh:) first understand the question and post your answer

Comment: select profession as d,(select max(sal) from emp where profession like d) as firstsal,

(select  sal from emp where profession like d order by sal desc limit 1,1) as secondsal

from emp  GROUP BY profession

Answer (score 1):

**For First Dept**

```
SELECT dept
FROM  `Table` 
WHERE dept = 'CSE'
ORDER BY sal DESC 
LIMIT 0 , 2
```

**For Second Dept**

```
SELECT dept
FROM  `Table` 
WHERE dept = 'ECE' 
ORDER BY sal DESC 
LIMIT 0 , 2
```

*Each Above Query will show you Top two results from each Dept.*

**UPDATE :**

```
SELECT dept, sal
FROM  `tbl_practice` 
WHERE dept =  'CSE'
OR dept =  'ECE'
ORDER BY sal DESC 
LIMIT 0 , 4
```

Comment: But I need single query to fetch all the records in each department

Answer (score 0):

you need to use an aggregate function `SUM` and a `GROUP BY` clause.

```
SELECT dept, SUM(Sal) TotalSalary
FROM tableName
GROUP BY dept
Order By TotalSalary DESC
Limit 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `LIMIT` in your statememt: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html

Answer (score 0):

Dont think in a single SQL statement you will be able to get the data. If you want to achieve it using SQL, you will need to use a stored procedure that will loop thru all the depts and fetch the top 2 salary rows using limit and order by.

Comment: select profession as d,(select max(sal) from emp where profession like d) as firstsal, (select sal from emp where profession like d order by sal desc limit 1,1) as secondsal from emp GROUP BY profession

Comment: Using limit and side by side columns any data can be retrieved. If that satisfies then great but I was hoping for the data to come in tabular manner so that programmatically it will be easier to handle the data and change or update in the future. It all depends on one's requirement! :) Congrats on the solution BTW!

Answer (score 0):

Try this Query

```
select * from (
 SELECT  DISTINCT dept
        FROM    tableName )a
join tableName b
on a.dept >=b.dept
and 
a.dept <=b.dept
and sal >=(
select sal from tableName 
  where a.dept=b.dept
  order by sal limit 1,1
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 select profession as d,(select max(sal) 
 from emp where profession like d) as firstsal,(
 select sal from emp 
 where profession like d order by sal desc limit 1,1) as secondsal from emp 
 GROUP BY profession
```